# How to take partial derivatives for total resistance?

Tags: calculus, partial-derivative

I working on differential problems for calculus. One problem asks to estimate max error on the total resistance of three parallel resistors, but I'm a bit stuck on how to take partial derivatives of the total resistance when it is itself expressed as a reciprocal.

$$ \frac{1}{R} =  \frac{1}{R_1} + \frac{1}{R_2} + \frac{1}{R_3}$$

How do you deal with the $R$ being expressed like this when taking the partial derivative?

I would have thought something like this:

$$ \frac{\partial{R}}{\partial{R_1}} = \frac{\frac{-1}{R^2}}{\frac{-1}{R_1^2}} = \frac{R_1^2}{R}   $$

But this appears to actually be the inverse of the partial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you take differentials,
$$
-\frac{dR}{R^2}=-\frac{dR_1}{R_1^2}-\frac{dR_2}{R_2^2}-\frac{dR_3}{R_3^2}
$$
Now, to find the partial of $R$ w.r.t. $R_1$ you take $dR_2=dR_3=0$ to find
$$
\frac{\partial R}{\partial R_1}=\frac{R^2}{R_1^2}.
$$

Comment: What are $dR$ and $dR_1$ getting set to that they both disappear?

Comment: They do not disappear. After you set $dR_2=dR_3=0$, you divide by $dR_1$ to get the derivative.

Comment: I think I see better now. Because it's a partial the $dR$/$dR_1$ uses the partial notation ? Also, how did you know to start by taking the differentials?

Comment: This is not fashionable nowadays, but finding differentials first is a universal method to find partial derivatives in implicit relations. Taking differentials is easy, you do not have to distinguish  between independent and dependent variables. After that, you fix whatever variables you have to to get the partials.

Comment: Of course you could have found $R$ explicitly as a function of $R_1,R_2,R_3$ but that would be a bit messy